# Read elements from XML and use them in a method

Tags: c#, xml, list

i have the following code which checks if some folders were created; The list of folders with full path is stored in an xml file.

```
namespace InstallationCheck
{
    public class Checking
    {
       public bool result()
        {

            bool returns = true;

         //Reads from xml file the element content from a tag line (ex: esecpath)
            string esecpath = Checking.CitXml("C:\\testconfig.xml", "esecpath");
            string agentpath = Checking.CitXml("C:\\testconfig.xml", "agentpath");
            string datapath = Checking.CitXml("C:\\testconfig.xml", "datapath");
            string debugpath = Checking.CitXml("C:\\testconfig.xml", "debugpath");
            string helppath = Checking.CitXml("C:\\testconfig.xml", "helppath");
            string patchpath = Checking.CitXml("C:\\testconfig.xml", "patchpath");

            // Compare the paths from XML with the paths of the app.
            List<bool> listtest = new List<bool>();
            listtest.Add((Directory.Exists(esecpath) == true));
            listtest.Add((Directory.Exists(agentpath) == true));
            listtest.Add((Directory.Exists(datapath) == true));
            listtest.Add((Directory.Exists(debugpath) == true));
            listtest.Add((Directory.Exists(patchpath) == true));
            listtest.Add((Directory.Exists(helppath) == true));

            //Cheking if any of paths are false
            foreach (bool varia in listtest)
            {
                returns = returns && varia;
            }
            return returns;  
        }

            // Reading from XML method
        public static string CitXml(string xmlpath, string field)
        {
            XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xmlpath);
            xmlReader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;

            xmlReader.ReadToDescendant(field);
            return xmlReader.ReadElementString(field);

        }


    }

}
```

Now i need to check if some files were created (many of them), to spare me of manualy adding all in to the code, i wonder how should i do it; i want the code to read the xml file and check if all of the files (from the xml) were created. So i wonder if someone of you can give an ideea, a hint (so i can go read about it), maybe a code example. Thank you.

Comment: Code tip: never write `== true`. You can just take all of those out, along with the parentheses, safely and easily.

Comment: Please tell me that `Checking.CitXml()` doesn't load the entire XML file and look for a single element, then return its value. And that you're doing this over, and over, and over... <edit>Never mind. Scroll down fail.</edit>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to see if any were created, re-write the code to be something like:

```
public bool result()
{    
    Dictionary<string, string> files = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    files.Add("esecpath", "C:\\testconfig.xml");
    // ... etc for each file

    // if you want to see if any don't exist, then use ...
    // if(files.Any(f => !File.Exists(f.Value)))

    // else, these are all the created files
    var createdFiles = files.Where(f => !File.Exists(f.Value));
    if(createdFiles.Count() > 0)
    {
        // A file doesn't exist!  Therefore you are creating it!
    }
    var directories = files.Select(f => Checking.CitXml(f.Value, f.Key));

    return directories.All(d => Directory.Exists(d));
}
```

Comment: Thank you (and to others for tips), as you can tell i am new in this domanin, i feel like i'm touching the tip of an iceberg (called c#). I think i formed an ideea about what should i do. I forgot to mention that i am cheking if another program (installation)  is creating the right folders/files.

Comment: I used a lot of Linq in my example, read-up/get a book on Linq, it will help a lot in the manipulation of lists.

Comment: ps if this answers your question, mark it so with a check-mark.  Or if you want more answers, just wait a bit someone else may post one.

Comment: If i do check it, will i get other responses ?

Comment: I search for all un-answered questions, so if others are like me, they wouldn't see it.  But I've had people post another answer to questions I've asked and marked answered before, so its possible.